# Set Fragment Width so When Changing Fragment the other fragment show some layout Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio, fragment

[IMAGE EXAMPLE](http://stack.imgur.com/r2Y7B.png)

[so, this is the image example of my program
i have 2 fragment that can be changed with swipe gesture
when i at the RED layout section (u can see the image) , i can swipe to left and show the green layout

usually, the green layout is fill all the screen, but that i want here is there is some of red layout shown at the screen

i already try to change the green layout size but it didnt work, can someone help me? thanks and sorry if anyone ever ask this kind of question

]

```
ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new CalcTab(), "Calc");
    adapter.addFragment(new HistTab(), "History");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

the red is CalcTab and green is HistTab
i want that when i change into HistTab, the CalcTab shown the 25% of its layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add padding to your `viewpager` as follows.

```
yourViewpager.setPadding(paddingvalue, 0, paddingvalue, 0);
yourViewpager.setClipToPadding(false);
```

and override following method in your viewpager adapter

```
@Override
public float getPageWidth(int position) {
    return 0.9f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting width is not the way, you can't do it like this, you must instantiate two Fragments and use a ViewPager with them.
Please take a look to my article about using `Fragment`s and `ViewPager`.
I think that's suitable for your case, you'll ind the gist of code as well.
[Take a look to the blog post](http://beraldofilippo.github.io/design/programming/android-build-a-quick-walkthrough-sliding-tutorial/)

Comment: sry, have you already read the last edit that i ask? please look at the image i give above, i want that the main layout show some side when i change to the second layout